# Find $x^{98}$ congruent to $7$ (mod $18$)

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences, totient-function

Find $x$, such that
$$x^{98} \equiv 7 \mod 18$$
holds.
Reminder: Euler's totient function is given by $$\phi(n) = n\prod_{p_i|n}\left(1-\frac1{p_i}\right).$$

I actually don't know, how to even approach this.
What is the common way, to approach this type of question?
How do i start solving this?
I tried simplifying to this:

\begin{align}
x^{98} &\equiv 7 \mod 2 \Rightarrow x^{98} ≡ 1 \mod 2\\
x^{98} &\equiv 7 \mod 9
\end{align}
but i'm not sure if this is the right approach.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So, what have you tried, on your own?  And your thought process while **addressing this problem that has been assigned to you**, and (**not MSE**).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to resort to [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem). You want to solve the equation 
$$x^{98}\equiv 7\,(\text{mod } 18).$$
This, in particular, would imply that $x^{98}=7 + 18\cdot n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, hence $x$ has to be coprime with $18$ (if $p$ divides $x$ and $18$, then it divides $x^{98}$ and $18$ and so $7$ as well, which is impossible). Thus you are in the hypothesis of Euler's Theorem: $x$ and $18$ are coprime and so
$$x^{\varphi(18)}\equiv 1\,(\text{mod } 18).$$
By repeatedly using this relation, you should be able to simplify your equation to something more handy.

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ is relatively prime to $18$ then $x^n$ has to be relatively prime to $18$ too.  There are only six residues modulo $18$ that do this, the rest are multiples of $2$ or $3$.  So $x^0=1, x^1=x, x^2, ...$ cycle among these six residues and you have $x^6\equiv x^0=1$.

Then $x^{98}\equiv x^{92}\equiv x^{86}\equiv ...$ and you get all the way down to $x^2$ where $2$ is the remainder when you divide $98$ by $6$.  And solving $x^2\equiv 7 \bmod 18$ will be easy.

Answer (score 2):

The form of Euler's totient function $\phi$ given there is not very practical, and I notice that you didn't give the value for $\phi(18)$. Here's it's easier to use that for $p$ prime, $\phi(p^k) = p^{k-1}(p-1)$ and that $\phi$ is multiplicative between coprime numbers.

So $\phi(18) = \phi(3^2)\phi(2) = 3^1(3-1)(2-1) = 6$.

Thus any number $a$ coprime to $18$ has $a^6\equiv 1 \bmod 18$ ([Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)).

Since $x^{98}\equiv 7$ is coprime to $18$, $x$ is also. Applying $x^6\equiv 1$ we can see that $x^{96}\equiv 1\bmod 18 $ and thus $x^{98}\equiv x^2\bmod 18$. By inspection, since $7+18=25$, we can see that $x\equiv 5$ is an answer to $x^2\equiv 7 \bmod 18$ and thus $x\equiv -5\equiv 13 \bmod 18$ is also an answer.

---

A couple of notes:

- Because we ended up looking for $x^2\equiv 7 \bmod 18$, we needed that $7$ is a quadratic residue $\bmod 18$, which is only true of half the values coprime to $18$. If the question had $5$ in place of $7$, there would be no answer.
- If we were looking at a modulus divisible by two odd primes, or by an odd prime and $4$, there would be more than two answers (for any soluble system). For example $x^2\equiv 13 \bmod 36$ has $x\equiv \{7, 11,25,29\}\bmod 36$.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers,

I hope I got it right so I solved this question for example:

Find the last digit of $7^{2013}$

so obviously

$7^{2013} ≡ x(mod 10)$

so my thought process was the same,
i know that $gcd(7,10)=1$

$φ(10)=φ(5-1)φ(2-1)=4$

then $(7^4)^{503}*7≡x(mod10)$

finally: 
$$7≡x(mod10)$$

so the final answer is 7, I hope I got it right...