# Finding a solution $x \in \mathbb{N}$ of $x^{125} \equiv 7 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 39)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I want to find a solution $x \in \mathbb{N}$ of $x^{125} \equiv 7 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 39)$ by using Ender Wiggin's method [Find $x^{98}$ congruent to $7$ (mod $18$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2378700/find-x98-congruent-to-7-mod-18)

My steps are:

$x^{125} \equiv 7 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 39) \Rightarrow x^{125}=7+39 \cdot n,\ n \in \mathbb{N}$

$\Rightarrow \mathrm{gcd}(x,39)=1$

It's $\varphi(39)=\varphi(3)\cdot\varphi(13)=24$

So $x^{24} \equiv 1 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 39)$

Since $x^{125} \equiv 7 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 3)$ and $x^{125} \equiv 7 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 13)$ it follows that

$x^{\varphi(3)}=x^2 \equiv 1  \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 3)$ and $x^{\varphi(13)}=x^{12} \equiv 1  \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 13)$.

Now I don't know what to do next.

I tried with $x=4$ and it works, but how to show it properly?

What has to be done now?

Comment: $39=3\times 13$ so it suffices to solve the problem $\pmod 3$ and $\pmod {13}$.

Comment: By [modular order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) it reduces to $\,x^5\equiv 7\,$ by $\,5 = 125\bmod 24,\,$ by $\, 24=\phi(39).\,$ As in the dupe, we can take the $5$'th root by raising to power $\,1/5\equiv 5/25\equiv 5\pmod{\!24}\,$ so $\,x\equiv 7^5\equiv -2\pmod{\!39}$

Answer (score 0):

Better use [Carmichael Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html) $$\lambda(39)=12$$

and $125\equiv5\pmod{12}$

$$ x^{125}\equiv x^5\pmod{39}$$

$$\implies x^5\equiv7\pmod{39}$$

Now as $x^{12}\equiv1\pmod{39}$

$$x\equiv(x^5)^5(x^{12})^{-2}\equiv7^5\cdot1^{-2}\pmod{39}$$

Finally $7^2\equiv10,7^4\equiv10^2\equiv-17, 7^5\equiv7(-17)\equiv-2\equiv39-2$

Comment: Carmichael doesn't gain anything, by $\,1/5\equiv 25/5\equiv 5\,$ is the same mod $24=\phi(n)$ as it is mod $12=\lambda(n)\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

$ x^{24} \equiv 1 \pmod{39} $ is not something to be solved; it's something you know is true whenever $\gcd(x,39)=1$. So

$$ x^{125} = (x^{24})^5 x^5 \equiv x^5 \equiv 7 \pmod{39} $$

Then you can continue as in [@lab bhattacharjee's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3677685/2236).

Or for a different approach, you could start by noting that $x^{125} \equiv 7 \pmod{39}$ if and only if $x^{125} \equiv 7 \pmod{3}$ and $x^{125} \equiv 7 \pmod{13}$.

Comment: Since $x^{125} \equiv 7 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 3)$ and $x^{125} \equiv 7 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 13)$ it follows that $x^{\varphi(3)}=x^2 \equiv 1  \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 3)$ and $x^{\varphi(13)}=x^{12} \equiv 1  \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 13)$. Now I don't know what to do next. I tried with $x=4$: $ 16 \equiv 1 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 3)$ and $ 16777216 \equiv 1 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 13)$, so it works. But how to show it properly?

Comment: Use the same idea of reducing the power. Since $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, $7 \equiv x^{125} = x^{124} x = (x^{2})^{62} x \equiv 1^{62} x = x \pmod 3$. Since $x^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$, $7 \equiv x^{125} = x^{120} x^5 = (x^{12})^{10} x^5 \equiv 1^{10} x = x \pmod{13}$.

Comment: 4 "works" for those two equations just because 4 is relatively prime to both 3 and 13. They will also be true for 2, 5, 7, 8, 10, .... but you're just verifying Fermat's Little Theorem. Again, the equations coming from Euler's Theorem aren't the things you want to solve; they're the helpful facts you want to use.

Comment: So $x^{125} \equiv x \equiv 7 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 3)$ and $x^{125} \equiv x \equiv 7 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 13)$. But how to conclude that $x=-2$, such that $-2^{125} \equiv 7 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 39)$?